# Finding euclidean distance in R{spatstat} between points, confined by an irregular polygon window

Tags: r, polygon, euclidean-distance, spatstat

I'm trying to find the euclidean distance between two points, confined by an irregular polygon. (ie. the distance would have to be calculated as a route through the window given)

Here is an reproducible example:

```
library(spatstat)

#Simple example of a polygon and points.
ex.poly <- data.frame(x=c(0,5,5,2.5,0), y=c(0,0,5,2.5,5))
points <- data.frame(x=c(0.5, 2.5, 4.5), y=c(4,1,4))

bound <- owin(poly=data.frame(x=ex.poly$x, y=ex.poly$y))

test.ppp <- ppp(x=points$x, y=points$y, window=bound)

pairdist.ppp(test.ppp)#distance between every point
#The distance result from this function between point 1 and point 3, is given as 4.0
```

However we know just from plotting the points

```
plot(test.ppp)
```

that the distance when the route is confined to the polygon should be greater (in this case, 5.00).

Is there another function that I am not aware of in {spatstat} that would do this? Or does anybody have any other suggestions for another package that could do this?

I'm trying to find the distance between two points in a water body, so the irregular polygon in my actual data is more complex.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Interesting question. I might suggest converting `bound` to a RasterLayer object (perhaps first using **maptools** to supply `as(bound, "SpatialPolygons")` and `as(test.ppp, "SpatialPoints")`), and then using the **gdistance** package to compute a "least-cost distance" between the points, with the friction or cost of all grid points outside of `bound` set to infinity. [**gdistance**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdistance/index.html) ships with a nice vignette (run `vignette("gdistance")` to see it) that should give you a good start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, here's the **gdistance**-based approach I mentioned in comments yesterday.  It's not perfect, since the segments of the paths it computes are all constrained to occur in one of 16 directions on a chessboard (king's moves plus knight's moves).  That said, it gets within 2% of the correct values (always slightly overestimating) for each of the three pairwise distances in your example.

```
library(maptools)  ## To convert spatstat objects to sp objects
library(gdistance) ## Loads raster and provides cost-surface functions

## Convert *.ppp points to SpatialPoints object
Pts <- as(test.ppp, "SpatialPoints")

## Convert the lake's boundary to a raster, with values of 1 for
## cells within the lake and values of 0 for cells on land
Poly <- as(bound, "SpatialPolygons")           ## 1st to SpatialPolygons-object
R <- raster(extent(Poly), nrow=100,  ncol=100) ## 2nd to RasterLayer ...
RR <- rasterize(Poly, R)                       ## ...
RR[is.na(RR)]<-0                               ## Set cells on land to "0"

## gdistance requires that you 1st prepare a sparse "transition matrix"
## whose values give the "conductance" of movement between pairs of
## adjacent and next-to-adjacent cells (when using directions=16)
tr1 <- transition(RR, transitionFunction=mean, directions=16)
tr1 <- geoCorrection(tr1,type="c")

## Compute a matrix of pairwise distances between points
## (These should be 5.00 and 3.605; all are within 2% of actual value).  
costDistance(tr1, Pts)
##          1        2
## 2 3.650282         
## 3 5.005259 3.650282

## View the selected paths
plot(RR)
plot(Pts, pch=16, col="gold", cex=1.5, add=TRUE)
SL12 <- shortestPath(tr1, Pts[1,], Pts[2,], output="SpatialLines")
SL13 <- shortestPath(tr1, Pts[1,], Pts[3,], output="SpatialLines")
SL23 <- shortestPath(tr1, Pts[2,], Pts[3,], output="SpatialLines")
lapply(list(SL12, SL13, SL23), function(X) plot(X, col="red", add=TRUE, lwd=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Great example using gdistance! I was trying to figure out a way to use a convex hull as well, but this is much better! Thanks!

Comment: Everything worked as needed, just the plotting to view the selected paths gave me the following error message:   `> SL12 <- shortestPath(tr1, Pts[1,], Pts[2,], output="SpatialLines")
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
      invalid class “CRS” object: invalid object for slot  "projargs" in class "CRS": got class "logical", should be or extend class "character"`

Comment: I won't be able to help you much without having your spatial data objects in front of me, and can only suggest that you carefully examine the projection metadata attached to both `tr1` and `Pts`, using `proj4string()`, `crs()`, `identicalCRS()`, etc. If they don't match up, you may need to project your points to the raster's CRS or take some other fiddly steps to make them match up. Best of luck!