# Find closest point while staying in a polygon?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two cities and one individual. I'd like to find the city that is closest to this individual. To do that, I can use `sf::st_nearest_feature()`. However, so far it only uses the distance as the crow flies between the individual and each city. I'd like to add the constraint that the path must stay inside a polygon.

In the example below:

- individual (red triangle) is closer to city A than to city B if we consider distance as the crow flies;
- however if we add the constraint that the individual can only move inside the polygon, then it is closer to city B.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(rnaturalearth)

background <- ne_countries(scale = 'small', type = 'map_units', returnclass = 'sf') |>
  subset(name %in% c("England", "Wales")) |> 
  st_union()

cities <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B"),
  lon = c(-4.3, -3.3),
  lat = c(51.2, 51.45)
) |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

individual <- data.frame(id = 1, lon = -4.3, lat = 51.6) |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = background) +
  geom_sf(data = cities, size = 3) +
  geom_sf(data = individual, color = "red", shape = 17, size = 3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-6, -1), ylim = c(50, 52)) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = cities, 
    aes(geometry = geometry, label = name),
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
  )
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may not
#> give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

`st_nearest_feature()` tells me that the nearest city is `A`:

```r
nearest <- st_nearest_feature(individual, cities)
cities[nearest, "name"]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -4.3 ymin: 51.2 xmax: -4.3 ymax: 51.2
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   name          geometry
#> 1    A POINT (-4.3 51.2)
```

How can I modify my measure of distance so that the nearest city is `B`? If possible, the solution should scale well to do this for millions of individuals (the number of cities will stay small) in a reasonable time.

Comment: There are a couple of solutions to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68596244/7547327

Answer (score 1):

You can create LINESTRING representations of the paths and use `st_contains()` to find which are fully inside the polygon. Then select the shortest one after having disqualified those not inside the polygon by setting them to infinity:

```r
paths <- st_cast(st_union(st_geometry(cities), st_geometry(individual)), 
                 'LINESTRING')
path.len <- st_length(paths)
path.len[!st_contains(background, paths, sparse=F)] <- Inf
cities[which.min(path.len), "name"]
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -3.3 ymin: 51.45 xmax: -3.3 ymax: 51.45
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   name           geometry
# 2    B POINT (-3.3 51.45)
```

### For more than one individual

Data:

```r
individual <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                         lon = -4.3 + c(.7, 0, 1), 
                         lat = 51.6 + c(-.3, 0, 0)) |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = background) +
  geom_sf(data = cities, size = 3) +
  geom_sf(data = individual, color = "red", shape = 17, size = 3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-6, -1), ylim = c(50, 52)) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = cities, 
    aes(geometry = geometry, label = name),
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
  ) + 
  geom_text_repel(
    data = individual, 
    aes(geometry = geometry, label = id),
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
  )
```

[image: three individuals and two cities]

Basically do the same succesively for each individual:

```r
nearest <- sapply(seq_along(st_geometry(individual)), \(i) {
  paths <- st_cast(st_union(st_geometry(cities), st_geometry(individual)[i]), 
                   'LINESTRING')
  path.len <- st_length(paths)
  path.len[!st_contains(background, paths, sparse=F)] <- Inf
  which.min(path.len)
})
cities[nearest, 'name']
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -4.3 ymin: 51.2 xmax: -3.7 ymax: 51.5
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#     name          geometry
# 1      A POINT (-4.3 51.2)
# 2      B POINT (-3.7 51.5)
# 2.1    B POINT (-3.7 51.5)
```

Comment: It works fine with 1 or 2 individuals, but if I have 3 (or more) then there's an error: `Error in recycle_common(x, as_s2_geography(y)) : Incompatible lengths: 2, 3`

Comment: @bretauv I see, you didn't indicate there would be more than one individual. See my updated answer.

Comment: It's in the last line of my post

Comment: Not explicitly, I understood *points* as cities. It would be best to create example data general enough to make this unambiguous.